# How to remove all strings from array that end with a specific character

Tags: arrays, bash, glob, end-of-line

I have an array containing a list of file paths within different levels of directories. I want to filter that array to only files,meaning those that end with an `/` should remain in the array. All paths are no real paths on my file system I could check the type using OS tools for directories/files.

I have an array with following strings:

```
file-a
dir/
dir/file-b
dir/dir-2/
dir/dir-2/file-c
```

And want to filter it to the following strings (no directories):

```
file-a
dir/file-b
dir/dir-2/file-c
```

I tried it with the following but that removes all paths including a `/`, resulting in `file-a` being the only remain.

```
FILES_ARRAY=( ${FILES_ARRAY[@]//*\/} )
```

I tried to add an `$` (as common in regex syntax) to denote the end which does not remove anything from the array.

```
FILES_ARRAY=( ${FILES_ARRAY[@]//*\$/} )
```

Comment: `${FILES_ARRAY[@]//*\/}` is not a regex, this syntax is specific to Bash string manipulation using globs.

Answer (score 2):

Two different solutions depending on what `filter` means:

1 - remove the directory entries from the array:

```
declare -a FILES_ARRAY=([0]="file-a" [1]="dir/" [2]="dir/file-b" [3]="dir/dir-2/" [4]="dir/dir-2/file-c")
echo "++++++++++++++ array - before"
printf "%s\n" ${FILES_ARRAY[@]}

for i in ${!FILES_ARRAY[@]}
do
    [[ "${FILES_ARRAY[${i}]}" == */ ]] && unset FILES_ARRAY[${i}]       # remove directory from array
done

echo "++++++++++++++ array - after"
printf "%s\n" ${FILES_ARRAY[@]}
```

This generates:

```
++++++++++++++ array - before
file-a
dir/
dir/file-b
dir/dir-2/
dir/dir-2/file-c
++++++++++++++ array - after
file-a
dir/file-b
dir/dir-2/file-c
```

2 - leave the directory entries in the array but don't display them; we can re-use the above code with a change to the body of the `for` loop:

```
declare -a FILES_ARRAY=([0]="file-a" [1]="dir/" [2]="dir/file-b" [3]="dir/dir-2/" [4]="dir/dir-2/file-c")
echo "++++++++++++++ array"
printf "%s\n" ${FILES_ARRAY[@]}

echo "++++++++++++++ display"
for i in ${!FILES_ARRAY[@]}
do
    [[ "${FILES_ARRAY[${i}]}" != */ ]] && echo "${FILES_ARRAY[${i}]}"   # only display non-directory entries
done
```

This also generates:

```
++++++++++++++ array
file-a
dir/
dir/file-b
dir/dir-2/
dir/dir-2/file-c
++++++++++++++ display
file-a
dir/file-b
dir/dir-2/file-c
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
FILES_ARRAY=(file-a dir/ dir/file-b dir/dir-2/ dir/dir-2/file-c)
NEW_FILES_ARRAY=()
for (( i=0; i<${#FILES_ARRAY[@]}; i++ )); do 
  if ! [[ "${FILES_ARRAY[$i]}" == */ ]]; then
    NEW_FILES_ARRAY+=("${FILES_ARRAY[$i]}");
  fi
done
FILES_ARRAY=("${NEW_FILES_ARRAY[@]}")

printf '%s\n' ${FILES_ARRAY[@]}
```

Output:

```
file-a
dir/file-b
dir/dir-2/file-c
```

See an [online Bash demo](https://ideone.com/oqepn9).

**NOTES**:

- `for (( i=0; i<${#FILES_ARRAY[@]}; i++ )); do ... done` iterates over the `FILES_ARRAY` length, `i` is assigned indices of the array elements
- `if ! [[ "${FILES_ARRAY[$i]}" == */ ]]` checks if the current element does not end with `/` (`*` matches any amount of any chars and `/` matches `/`, the *glob* pattern always requires entire string match, no need for `$`) and
- `NEW_FILES_ARRAY+=("${FILES_ARRAY[$i]}");` adds the current item to the `NEW_FILES_ARRAY` array.
- `FILES_ARRAY=("${NEW_FILES_ARRAY[@]}")` reassigns the original variable so that it holds the filtered elements

Comment: That example does not completely work because we are altering the array while iterating it. This way, the last entry is not handled and `dir/dir-2/file-c` is missing.

Comment: @SebastianBarth Ok, I adjusted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This `awk` command may help, but it'll fail with spaces in paths

```
new_arr=($(awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i !~ /\/$/) {print $i}}' <<< "${arr[@]}"))
```